# Show first item differently with FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-recyclerview

I have an app were I have a list of "Games" in firebase and a users that belong to that game.
I am displaying the details of the game of a certain user in a Recyclerview using FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter

```js
  "Games" : {
    "-Kk6_Y05XnmWpxrhjdg2" : {
      "confirmedPlayers" : {
        "cahTG4Fp5XUOOU8TGnyf8S35PVN2" : true
      },
      "missingPlayers" : 9,
      "name" : "GoogleGame",
      "noPlayers" : 5,
      "timestamp" : "201706151200"
    },
    "-Kk7u9kbcLmVfq3i2kiK" : {
      "confirmedPlayers" : {
        "cahTG4Fp5XUOOU8TGnyf8S35PVN2" : true
      },
      "missingPlayers" : 9,
      "name" : "nico game",
      "noPlayers" : 5,
      "timestamp" : "201706151800"
    },
    "-KkGfriMuqnw2DrnpsW-" : {
      "confirmedPlayers" : {
        "cahTG4Fp5XUOOU8TGnyf8S35PVN2" : true
      },
      "missingPlayers" : 9,
      "name" : "santi",
      "noPlayers" : 5,
      "timestamp" : "201706171100"
    }
  },
  "UserGames" : {
    "cahTG4Fp5XUOOU8TGnyf8S35PVN2" : {
      "confirmed" : {
        "-Kk6_Y05XnmWpxrhjdg2" : "201706151200",
        "-Kk7u9kbcLmVfq3i2kiK" : "201706151800",
        "-KkGfriMuqnw2DrnpsW-" : "201706171100"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here the code

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userGamesRef = root.child("UserGames").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
DatabaseReference confirmedRef = userGamesRef.child("confirmed");
DatabaseReference gamesRef = root.child("Games");

gameListFirebaseAdapter = getFirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapterInstance(confirmedRef, gamesRef);

gameListFirebaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
  @Override
  public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
    super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
    int gamesViewCount = gameListFirebaseAdapter.getItemCount();
    int lastVisiblePosition =
      gameListLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
      (positionStart >= (gamesViewCount - 1) &&
        lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
      gameListRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
    }
  }
});

gameListRecyclerView.setAdapter(gameListFirebaseAdapter);
```

However I would like to display the first item in a diferent format (different view).

What approach do  you recomend?

**Failed attempt 1#:** I was not able to do a query that excludes the first item and pass that to FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter. (and display the first item in a different view)
I believe because FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter receives the DatabaseReference and if there was a query before you loose it.

```
DatabaseReference filteredDbRef = confirmedRef.orderByValue().startAt("201506151800").getRef();
gameListFirebaseAdapter = getFirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapterInstance(filteredDbRef, gamesRef);
```

**Pending Attempt:** Stop using FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter do a addChildEventListener with nested addListenerForSingleValueEvent and somehow add one by one the items to the recyclerview. (and display the first item in a different view)

Comment: Did you see the discussion about handling multiple view types here? https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/305

Comment: Thanks! Nice Finding! I got it working with a simple conbination of ValueEventListener and queries, but I will definetively try this other solution as well. Thanks!